# Zoneminder installation. What version?

Tags: raspbian, apt, aptitude, zoneminder

On the default Debian repository the Zoneminder package available is the version `1.26`, however the last version is `1.29` (with a functionality I need).

Following the advise on [Zoneminder 1.29](https://wiki.zoneminder.com/Debian_8_64-bit_with_Zoneminder_1.29.0_the_Easy_Way) I added the repository (*)

```
deb http://http.debian.net/debian jessie-backports main
```

then I confirmed that the last version is available:

```
$ apt-cache policy zoneminder
zoneminder:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.26.5-3.1+rpi1+b12
  Version table:
     1.29.0+dfsg-1~bpo8+1 0
        100 http://http.debian.net/debian/ jessie-backports/main armhf Packages
     1.26.5-3.1+rpi1+b12 0
        500 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main armhf Packages
```

however, the 'Candidate' is version '1.26.5'. I can force the new version installation with

```
apt-get install zoneminder=1.29.0*
```

but doing so, Zoneminder fail to start.

How does app-get determine the Candidate, I this case, not the last version?

*(*) GPG keys will be required*

Comment: Are you getting any errors when you try to start it?

Comment: Actually, look like the 1.29 does not perform (or finish) the full configuration part: MySQL is installed but there is no **zm** database.

Comment: You have to create it. Finish reading the page you posted the link to

Comment: I finish the installation as the page indicated, however, there are a few steps missing to make it work. My original question was not about Zoneminder, was about apt-get and the criteria to select the installation candidate. Missing steps are a few `chown www-data:www-data ...` and to config apache2 to point to "/usr/share/zoneminder/www/".

Comment: Yeah that has nothing to do with apt. If you didn't already have Apache installed and correctly configured then that's a completely different issue

Answer (score 1):

I have installed zoneminder 1.29 successfully on my raspberry pi 3.
Please refer my following web site for more details [how-to-install-zoneminder-1-29-0-on-raspberry-pi-3](https://bkjaya.wordpress.com/2016/11/23/how-to-install-zoneminder-1-29-0-on-raspberry-pi-3-with-raspbian-8-1-jessy-64-bit/)

Using the terminal

Add The Jessie backports

sudo gedit  /etc/apt/sources.list

Then add following line to the bottom of the file and save

deb http://http.debian.net/debian jessie-backports main

There are signature errors can be found

To fix those errors run following on the terminal

gpg --keyserver pgpkeys.mit.edu --recv-key  8B48AD6246925553
gpg -a --export 8B48AD6246925553 | sudo apt-key add -
gpg --keyserver pgpkeys.mit.edu --recv-key  7638D0442B90D010
gpg -a --export 7638D0442B90D010 | sudo apt-key add -

Then run on the terminal

sudo apt-get update

Now if you check the software center you can see the latest zoneminder version 1.29 on it .

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help). Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it is preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. In fact we're [enforcing this policy](http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/842/5538): please edit so that the answer stands on its own should the link break in the future. If it is not edited within 48 hours it will be converted to Community Wiki.

Comment: Using the terminal

Add The Jessie backports

sudo gedit  /etc/apt/sources.list

Then add following line to the bottom of the file and save

deb http://http.debian.net/debian jessie-backports main
There are signature errors can be found

To fix those errors run following on the terminal

gpg --keyserver pgpkeys.mit.edu --recv-key  8B48AD6246925553
gpg -a --export 8B48AD6246925553 | sudo apt-key add -
gpg --keyserver pgpkeys.mit.edu --recv-key  7638D0442B90D010
gpg -a --export 7638D0442B90D010 | sudo apt-key add -

 

Then run on the terminal

sudo apt-get update

Answer (score 1):

I install Zoneminder 1.32.3 on Raspberry Pi 3B+ with Debian 10 "Buster" version.

1. download on [page](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) Raspbian Buster with desktop and recommended software 
   use [Etcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/) to flash SD card
2. use this link https://forums.zoneminder.com/viewtopic.php?t=28389 to install
   zoneminder 1.32.3

   use root :

   ```
   sudo su
   ```
3. when zoneminder is installed, test zmaudit perl script :

   ```
   $ zmaudit.pl
   ```

   and if an error appears, use :

   ```
   $ cpan install Number::Bytes::Human
   ```
4. test http://localhost/zm/api/host/getVersion.json, if you not see :

   ```
   {     "version": "1.32.3",
        "apiversion": "1.0" }
   ```

   edit `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/zoneminder.conf` :

   ```
   $ nano /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/zoneminder.conf
   ```

   comment :

   ```
   <Directory "/usr/share/zoneminder/www/api">
           AllowOverride All
   </Directory>
   ```

   add :

   ```
   <Directory "/usr/share/zoneminder/www/api">
       RewriteEngine on
           RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/ [L]
           RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
           RewriteBase /zm/api
   </Directory>

   <Directory "/usr/share/zoneminder/www/api/app">
          RewriteEngine on
          RewriteRule ^$ webroot/ [L]
          RewriteRule (.*) webroot/$1 [L]
          RewriteBase /zm/api
       </Directory>

   <Directory "/usr/share/zoneminder/www/api/app/webroot">
           RewriteEngine On
           RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
           RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
           RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
           RewriteBase /zm/api
   </Directory>
   ```

   save and reload apache conf

   ```
   $ systemctl reload apache2
   ```
5. If problem with mariadb database not started : check path pid-file and socket paths between /etc/zm/zm.conf and files paths :

   ```
   $ ls /var/mysql or ls /var/run/mysql

   $ nano /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf
   ```

   (need to add /run/ on my config)

   ```
   pid-file                = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
   socket                  = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
   ```
6. reboot system

test http://localhost/zm, see log zoneminder, log apache

have fun !

Answer (score 0):

I did the same thing and found better instructions on the wiki. For some reason they don't list it on their main page. It had instructions to get the source GPG keys and there were some appendices that were missing.

https://wiki.zoneminder.com/Raspbian